# jquery Bootstrap tooltip title callback function not executing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, tooltip

When creating tooltips the following code should be used to change the shown content of the tooltip to whatever is returned by the function in the title option:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltip({
            html: true,
            title: function(el){return 'custom content';}
        });
```

The tooltip's are not shown at all or return the title attribute contents, but the callback function is not executed at all. No warnings/errors are shown in the console.

Comment: This whole question and answer line boils down to "pay attention to, and know, what libraries you are actually using".

Comment: Indeed, but I strongly think (or hope?) I'm not the only one on earth with this problem and just looking for 'why the callback is not executing'. Therefor I created this question + answer.

Comment: Sure, but my point is how many different combinations of question + answer are possible following this line of questioning?  They don't really offer much long term support.  "Know what you're using" should be a developer "duh".

Comment: You might have searched for this problem on Stack Overflow and not found the answer.  The reason you've not found the answer is because this question gets asked maybe 3-4 times a week and each time gets closed with the option: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."*

Answer (score -1):

Please be absolutely sure you are using Twitter Bootstrap's Tooltip and not jquery-ui !
This was the second time I pulled my hairs out, just look if jquery-ui is loaded or not in your html! In case jui is used, use the 'content' property:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltip({
            html: true,
            content: function(el){return 'custom content';}
        });
```